# How can I check the extension of the input file?Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using filedialog. askopenfilenames for the file. I always need to get ONLY a .txt file for input, as I can when choosing not .txt file display a message that the wrong file format is selected

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wX7s9SXB

Comment: Please update your question to add your code instead of relying on an external service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `askopenfilename` is better than `askopenfilenames` so I use `askopenfilename`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

screen=Tk()
screen.title("Simple project")
screen.geometry("600x300")

def Open():
    file=filedialog.askopenfilename()
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(str(file))
    print(extension)

bt=Button(screen,text="Open",command=Open).pack()
screen.mainloop()
```